# how to set a variable automatically zero for each midnight in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how to set a variable automatically zero for each midnight in node js is it possible to use node-schedule-npm ? if so please help me how to do it
initially var count= 0; when action is performed, it will get incremented throughout the day, for next day it should be automatically set to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
   var cron = require('node-schedule');
   cron.scheduleJob('00 00 12 * * 1-7',function setVotesToZero(req, res, next) {
    db.users.find().toArray(function(err, vote) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        db.users.update({}, {
            $set: {
               count : 0
            },
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send({
                status: 'success',
            });
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use node-cron from npm.

```
$ npm install --save node-cron
```

Here is an example code

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});

 # ┌────────────── second (optional)
 # │ ┌──────────── minute
 # │ │ ┌────────── hour
 # │ │ │ ┌──────── day of month
 # │ │ │ │ ┌────── month
 # │ │ │ │ │ ┌──── day of week
 # │ │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │ │
 # * * * * * *
```